# How do I add the $i parameter as a new property?

Tags: powershell

How do I add the value of $i as a new parameter to the object so that if $i is part of distinguishedName?

```
param([string[]]$Country="Norway,Denmark")
foreach ($i in $Country)
{
    $users += Get-ADUser -searchbase "ou=$i,ou=FMS,dc=ce,dc=xxxx,dc=net" -ldapfilter $ldapfilter -properties CN,SamAccountName,mail,title,department,company,pager,employeeNumber,distinguishedName,extensionAttribute12
    $users | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "OOU" -Force -Value ""
    {missing code to add $i as value for property .OOU}
}
$users | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "license" -Force -Value ""
$users | where extensionAttribute12 -Like "*EOP1*" | %{$_.license="EOP1"}
$users | where extensionAttribute12 -Like "*E1*" | %{$_.license="E1"}
$users | where extensionAttribute12 -Like "*E3*" | %{$_.license="E3"}
```

I have tried to do the same as with the where clause in the bottom part, but the foreach loop makes it overwrite all values with the last member of $i

Comment: Are you actually trying to update an AD object or just attach a new property to the object?

Comment: Replace `-Value ""` with `-Value $id`

Comment: It will not work since the foreach loop will overwrite the value when looping. And I am trying to add a new field to the object with information that can be exported later on to my excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-Value` parameter to specify the initial value of a new property:

```
$users | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "OOU" -Force -Value $i
```

To avoid re-assigning the newest values to all the existing users that have already received their new `OOP` property, use an intermediary variable to hold the output from `Get-ADUser`:

```
foreach ($i in $Country)
{
    $country_users = Get-ADUser -searchbase "ou=$i,ou=FMS,dc=ce,dc=xxxx,dc=net" -ldapfilter $ldapfilter -properties CN,SamAccountName,mail,title,department,company,pager,employeeNumber,distinguishedName,extensionAttribute12
    $users += @($country_users | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "OOU" -Force -Value $i)
}
```

Comment: That will not work, because of the foreach loop it will populate the OOU value with "Denmark" for all entries as the value for $i is "Denmark" in the second loop

Comment: @MortenLunde And what exactly should the value be?

Comment: While looping it should be Norway when it does the foreach loop with Norway as value, then it should be Denmark for the loop where Denmark is the value for $i. If there had been a third value for $i that is Sweden, the third round it should been set to Sweden.

Comment: But that's already the case - strings are passed by copy, `$i` doesn't "update" after you've added the new member.

Comment: @MortenLunde Ahh, I see the problem, you keep re-adding the new member to users you've already processed previously. See updated answer

Comment: Hmm. tried this, but now it seems to loop the list of Norway users multiple times and no entries in the list for Denmark users at all.